# Setting up an USB webcam RTSP stream with GStreamer

Tags: raspberry-pi, gstreamer, vlc, rtsp, v4l2

I'm using GStreamer to send the camera feed of `/dev/video1` (Raspberry Pi's usb webcam) through a RTSP server that I can connect with another Raspberry Pi.

Result of `v4l2-ctl -d /dev/video1 --list-formats`:

```
ioctl: VIDIOC_ENUM_FMT
    Type: Video Capture

    [0]: 'MJPG' (Motion-JPEG, compressed)
    [1]: 'YUYV' (YUYV 4:2:2)
```

The pipeline I'm using is

```
./gst-rtsp-launch --port 8555 '( v4l2src device='/dev/video1 ! image/jpeg,width=800,height=600,framerate=30/1 ! jpegparse ! rtpjpegpay name=pay0 pt=96 )' --gst-debug-level=3`
```

When running it, and letting the other machine connect, the console gives this message:

```
0:00:02.097412343  3234 0xb4c1c0c0 FIXME                default gstutils.c:3981:gst_pad_create_stream_id_internal:<appsrc0:src> Creating random stream-id, consider implementing a deterministic way of creating a stream-id
0:00:02.102907578  3234 0xb5a07600 WARN                 v4l2src gstv4l2src.c:692:gst_v4l2src_query:<v4l2src0> Can't give latency since framerate isn't fixated !
0:00:02.170888076  3234 0xb4c1b980 WARN          v4l2bufferpool gstv4l2bufferpool.c:790:gst_v4l2_buffer_pool_start:<v4l2src0:pool:src> Uncertain or not enough buffers, enabling copy threshold
0:00:02.410829991  3234  0x166ba90 FIXME              rtspmedia rtsp-media.c:3581:gst_rtsp_media_suspend: suspend for dynamic pipelines needs fixing
0:00:02.414457433  3234  0x166ba90 FIXME              rtspmedia rtsp-media.c:3581:gst_rtsp_media_suspend: suspend for dynamic pipelines needs fixing
0:00:02.414551635  3234  0x166ba90 WARN               rtspmedia rtsp-media.c:3607:gst_rtsp_media_suspend: media 0xb5a34130 was not prepared
0:00:03.878249884  3234  0x166ba90 WARN               rtspmedia rtsp-media.c:3868:gst_rtsp_media_set_state: media 0xb5a34130 was not prepared
```

On the client Raspberry Pi, using VLC on the static IP `vlc rtsp://192.168.0.10:8555/video`, gives this error (and triggers the previous one in the other board):

```
mmal: mmal_component_create_core: could not create component 'vc.ril.hvs' (1)
mmal: mmal_vc_component_create: failed to create component 'vc.ril.hvs' (1:ENOMEM)
mmal: mmal_component_create_core: could not create component 'vc.ril.hvs' (1)
mmal: mmal_vc_component_create: failed to create component 'vc.ril.hvs' (1:ENOMEM)
mmal: mmal_component_create_core: could not create component 'vc.ril.hvs' (1)
mmal: mmal_vc_component_create: failed to create component 'vc.ril.hvs' (1:ENOMEM)
mmal: mmal_component_create_core: could not create component 'vc.ril.hvs' (1)
mmal: mmal_vc_port_info_set: failed to set port info (3:0): EINVAL
mmal: mmal_vc_port_set_format: mmal_vc_port_info_set failed 0x909bcaa0 (EINVAL)
Falha de segmentação
```

The last line means "Segmentation fault". The screen in the client board flickers black before giving this error, and the board connect to the webcam only shows this error after the client connected.

Connecting to localhost on the same board using `vlc rtsp://127.0.0.1:8555/video` works for a little bit, then it breaks.

How can I fix this pipeline, so the video can be shown correctly through connection between the two boards?

Comment: Which version of gstreamer are you using?

Comment: @JonasVautherin gst-launch-1.0 version 1.14.4

Comment: That's fairly old, latest is 1.20.1: https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/. Maybe you should try that? I mean a "segmentation fault" here sounds like maybe something got fixed in the meantime :)

Comment: @JonasVautherin You are correct, it was an outdated version! Version 1.18.4 worked fine here. Can you send your comment as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the record:

I asked in the comments which version of gstreamer you were using, to which the answer was "1.14.4".

I suggested you update to the latest version (1.20.1), because a segmentation fault where you see it sounds like a potential bug in gstreamer.

Turns out that it was correct: updating gstreamer (to 1.18.4) resolved the problem!